# swift- Assigning the value to the custom button from subview

Tags: swift

Hi I'm trying to assign the particular subview  in custom buttons  in for loop it is working fine in objective c, but I'm facing problem in swift code.

objective c code:

```
    HButton *view = nil; // hbutton class object
     NSArray *subviews = [self.superview subviews]; // storing the subviews in subviews array
     NSInteger i = 0;    // for index
    for (view in subviews)
     {
             if ([view isKindOfClass:[HButton class]])
            {
               HButton *check=[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            if (self.tag == check.tag)
             {
                    self.titleLabel.text =@"hel";
                     self.backgroundColor =[UIColor orangeColor];
             }
        i++;
    }
```

Swift Code:

```
    var view1 :BTNCustom! = nil
    var subviews : NSArray = self.superview.subviews

    var  ival : Int = 0;
    for view1 : AnyObject  in subviews // I'm getting the error in this line
    {
    if view1.isKindOfClass(BTNCustom)
    {
    var check : BTNCustom = subviews.objectAtIndex(ival) as BTNCustom
    if (self.tag == check.tag)
{
self.titleLabel.text = "hel";
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}
ival++;
}
}
```

Comment: "I'm getting the error" Please state what error you get

Comment: what error are you getting??

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear what you are actually trying to do? The following is the closest thing I can imagine to what you are trying to do:

```
for view in superview.subviews {
  if view.isKindOfClass(BTNCustom) && tag == view.tag {
    titleLabel.text = "hel"
    backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
  }
}
```

However, it really looks like you are abusing tags and not really understanding the point of a type system.

Specific problems with your code:

1) `var view1 :BTNCustom! = nil` you are assigning nil to something that you are saying you want to be automatically unwrapped, why not just `var view1: BTNCustom!`, they should be the same but the latter is much more palatable.

2) You are trying to use `view1` as your loop variable of a different type when you have already declared it to be BTNCustom. Why? Are you really using variable names like this? Do you have a limit on the number of characters you are allowed to use?

3) What is the point of using an extra integer to pull views out of the subview array when in fact that view is exactly the one you are already have a reference to? To be clear, in your Obj-C code, both `view` and `check` will always be identical whenever you actually use `check`.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to solved your error may this will help you!

```
for index in 1...subviews
{
    let view1:AnyObject = subViews[index] as AnyObject
    if view1.isKindOfClass(BTNCustom)
    {
           var check : BTNCustom = subviews.objectAtIndex(ival) as BTNCustom
           if (self.tag == check.tag)
           {
               self.titleLabel.text = "hel";
               self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            }
            ival++;
    }
}
```